# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 57

Tags: java, regex

I get an error for my regex

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 57
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\]{2}[\s]{1}[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]+
```

I dont know what is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: because of [\\]{2}

Answer (score 1):

The third `\` is followed by `]` directly:

```
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\]{2}[\s]{1}[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]+
                ^^^ missing 's' or 'd'?
```